# React how to repopulate values when back button clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In react js i get value from api then i used component to populated vale after back button clicked i don`t want to remove my value i want to my current data that work in text filed but it not work on
select it always remove it value.it show error name not defined.

i want repopulate select when clicked back button

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { QsrQoreApi, Eats365, StoreHub } from './Sources';
import SourceStoreSelection from './SourceStoreSelection';

import svgs from '../../shared/svgs';
import { Modal, withAuth } from '../../shared';

const StyledSourceSettings = styled.div`
  & .header {
    display: flex;
    height: 5.2rem;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #edf2f7;
  }

  & .back {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }

  & .title {
    margin-left: max(1.5rem, calc(((100vw - 21rem) / 2) - 4rem));
    width: 21rem;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2d3748;
  }

  & .source-form {
    padding: 2rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  & .login {
    width: 28rem;
    margin: 0 auto 0.4rem auto;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2d3748;
  }

  & .form-input {
    margin: 1.5rem auto 0 auto;
    width: 28rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: #4a5568;
  }

  & .form-input > .input {
    width: 28rem;
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
    height: 3.6rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid #a0aec0;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    color: #4a5568;
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  & .form-input > .select {
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
  }

  & .buffer-152px {
    height: 15.2rem;
  }

  & .buffer-91px {
    height: 9.1rem;
  }

  & .selected-store {
    width: 28rem;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2d3748;
  }

  & .selected-store-detail {
    display: flex;
    height: 5.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #edf2f7;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: #4a5568;
  }

  & .selected-store-detail > .map {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
  }

  & .selected-store-detail > .name {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 22rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }

  & .selected-store-detail > .forward {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }

  & .next-btn {
    width: 28rem;
    height: 3.6rem;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: max(5.3rem, calc(100vh - 47.1rem));
    border: 0.1rem solid #cbd5e0;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0rem 0.2rem 0.4rem rgba(24, 39, 75, 0.12);
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4a5568;
  }

  & .next-btn:disabled,
  & .next-btn[disabled] {
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #cbd5e0;
  }
`;

const sourceOpts = [
  { value: 'QsrQoreApi', label: 'QsrQoreApi' },
  { value: 'Eats365', label: 'Eats365' },
  { value: 'StoreHub', label: 'StoreHub' },
];

const sourceSelectStyles = {
  control: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    width: '28rem',
    minHeight: '3.6rem',
    height: '3.6rem',
    fontSize: '1.6rem',
    border: '0.1rem solid #a0aec0',
    borderRadius: '0.4rem',
    color: '#4a5568',
  }),
  indicatorSeparator: () => {},
  singleValue: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: '#4a5568',
  }),
  valueContainer: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    padding: '0.2rem 0.8rem',
  }),
  placeholder: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    margin: 'auto 0.2rem',
  }),
  input: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    margin: '0.2rem',
    padding: '0.2rem auto',
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    '& svg': {
      height: '2rem',
      width: '2rem',
    },
  }),
  indicatorsContainer: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    '& > div': {
      padding: '0.8rem',
    },
  }),
  menu: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    borderRadius: '0.4rem',
    margin: '0.8rem auto',
  }),
  menuList: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    maxHeight: '30rem',
    padding: '0.4rem 0',
  }),
  option: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    padding: '0.8rem 1.2rem',
  }),
};

function AddSource(props) {
  const { setForm, store, setStore , source} = props;


  const [sourceAdditionalInfos, setSourceAdditionalInfos] = React.useState({});
  const [sourceStore, setSourceStore] = React.useState(null);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(store.source){
      const infos = store.source.additionalInfos.reduce((result, { key, value }) => {
        const temp = result;
        temp[key] = value;
        return temp;
      }, {});
      setSourceAdditionalInfos(infos);
    }  
  },[]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
      if (store.source) {
        const infospos = store.source.type
        const value = infospos;
        setSourceStore(value);
      }
  },[]);


  const onBackClick = () => {
    navigate(-1);
  };

  const onSourceSelectChange = (source) => {
    if (source) {
      setStore({ ...store, source: { type: source.value } });
      setSourceStore(null);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => setSourceAdditionalInfos({ ...sourceAdditionalInfos, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!sourceStore) setShowModal(true);
    else {
      const addInfos = Object.entries(sourceAdditionalInfos).map(([k, v]) => ({ key: k, value: v }));
      let st = {
        ...store,
        source: {
          ...store.source,
          ...sourceStore.value,
          additionalInfos: addInfos.concat(sourceStore.value.additionalInfos),
        },
      };

      setStore(st);
      setForm('addStore');
    }
  };

  let renderSource = <div className="buffer-152px" />;
  if (store.source) {
    switch (store.source.type) {
      case 'QsrQoreApi':
        renderSource = (
          <QsrQoreApi
            handleChange={handleChange}
            sourceAdditionalInfos={sourceAdditionalInfos}
            disableInput={sourceStore}
          />
        );
        break;
      case 'Eats365':
        renderSource = (
          <Eats365
            handleChange={handleChange}
            sourceAdditionalInfos={sourceAdditionalInfos}
            disableInput={sourceStore}
          />
        );
        break;
      case 'StoreHub':
        renderSource = (
          <StoreHub
            handleChange={handleChange}
            sourceAdditionalInfos={sourceAdditionalInfos}
            disableInput={sourceStore}
          />
        );
        break;
      default:
        renderSource = <div className="buffer-152px" />;
        break;
    }
  }

  let renderSelectedSourceStore = '';
  if (sourceStore) {
    renderSelectedSourceStore = (
      <>
        <div className="selected-store">Store selection</div>
        <div className="selected-store-detail" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
          <img src={svgs.map} className="map" alt="map" />
          <div className="name">{sourceStore.value.name}</div>
          <img src={svgs.forward} className="forward" alt="forward" />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    renderSelectedSourceStore = <div className="buffer-91px" />;
  }

  return (
    <StyledSourceSettings>
      <div className="header">
        <img src={svgs.back} className="back" alt="back" onClick={onBackClick} />
        <div className="title">POS System</div>
      </div>
      <form className="source-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="login">Login credentials</div>
        <label className="form-input" htmlFor="type">
          <div className="label">POS System</div>
          <div className="select">
            <Select
              options={sourceOpts}
              styles={sourceSelectStyles}
              placeholder="Choose one"
              onChange={onSourceSelectChange}
              inputId="type"
              isDisabled={sourceStore}
            />
          </div>
        </label>
        {renderSource}
        {renderSelectedSourceStore}
        <input className="next-btn" type="submit" value="NEXT" disabled={!(store.source && store.source.type)} />
      </form>
      <Modal onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} open={showModal}>
        <SourceStoreSelection
          onSubmitted={() => setShowModal(false)}
          onClosed={() => setShowModal(false)}
          store={store}
          sourceAdditionalInfos={sourceAdditionalInfos}
          sourceStore={sourceStore}
          setSourceStore={setSourceStore}
        />
      </Modal>
    </StyledSourceSettings>
  );
}

export default withAuth(AddSource);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeiaE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to:

```
{sourceStore?.value?.name}
```

Comment: error not show but still select not show suitable data